# How can i make a randomly generated 2D polygon map in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a 2D infinte runner in Unity. The main issue is how can i create a 2D map like the following
[image]

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: I did try using meshes But, i'm a beginner when it comes to using meshes so i didn't really know how to use triangles in order to create a shape like the one in the picture

Comment: Take a certain amount (can also be random) of vertexes you spread - either equal or again random - over the X axis, do it twice (one is the bottom line the other the top line) .. to the bottom line set all Y values on e.g. `0` or whatever your screen bottom is .. finally iterate through the top line and assign random values for Y .. the easiest thing is later triangulate the resulting mesh between the top and bottom line ;)